# What's good practice for <button>? Can it replace <a> or is it only meant for forms?

Tags: html, user-interface

What's good practice for `<button>`?

Can it replace `<a>` tag or is it only meant for forms?

Comment: @Mike, I've edited your question assuming that `<buttons>` was just a typo. Feel free to revert the edit if I was wrong.

Comment: Buttons are used to provide an intuitive control to perform some action. If a user has to submit, cancel, update, "do something", buttons will not make a user think about what to do and will be the obvious control to use. It doesn't have to be `<button>` but should look like one.

Comment: And what about `<input type="button">`? Are *those* just for forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A link *links* to something - at least it should! It is semantically wrong to do the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">Do something</a>
```

This should be replaced with a button, as it is there for that purpose - it works as a trigger for something the user (programmer) specifies; the purpose of a `<button type="button">` element is thus not clear. In contrast, the purpose of a link is very clear - it should point somewhere!

As HTML is a markup language, it does not matter all that much what you do, if you do not think SEO. You can achieve the same thing with a `<a>`tag as you can with a `<button>` tag, like a `<span>` can act exactly as a `<div>` - **semantically though, it is incorrect**.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on company conventions really, but with my experience `buttons` are typically used when the page does not redirect (including, but not limited to forms), and an `<a>` for when the user is directed to a new page.

Comment: This is my convention as well.

Comment: I think using buttons(or, a button like element) to redirect to a page to perform an action is appropriate as well. For example, "Register". On the other hand, `<a>`(rather, a link) should be used to direct towards information, which includes scrolling to an appropriate section of the same page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `<button>` tag to replace a regular link (`<a href="...">`) you'll have the following disadvantages:

- It won't look like a link so it'll just add confusion.
- You need to use JavaScript to make the button do something.
- Search engines and other tools will not be able to follow the link.
- You won't have visual indication for visited links.
- Users can no longer decide to open the link in a new tab, inspect the destination or copy the URL.

I can't think of any advantage right now.

Comment: `<a href=foo><button>hello</button></a>` is not recommended – but possible.

Comment: I totally agree with you but you can almost style a button like a link: http://jsfiddle.net/MsKWX/

Comment: @toscho - That's [explicitly disallowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button#Usage_context).

Answer (score 1):

A `<button>` is for form elements only. In Opera you navigate links with <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Arrow, form elements are accessible per <kbd>tab</kbd>.

So, no, you shouldn’t replace one element with the other.